# How to use singleton over multiple assemblies in design time

Tags: silverlight, singleton, design-time

I have 3 assemblies:

- MyApp.Views (uses MyApp.Data and MyApp.Metadata)
- MyApp.Data (uses MyApp.Metadata)
- MyApp.Metadata

I have an interface, say IMetadata. Then, I also have an implementation in MyApp.Metadata which I register in a singleton class:

```
IoCContainer.Instance.Register<IMetadata, Metadata>();
```

Then, in design time, I use an assembly that needs to use the metadata (but it's the MyApp.Data that resolves the type):

```
IoCContainer.Instance.ResolveType<IMetadata>();
```

But this fails. The IoCContainer.Instance does not contain the same interfaces (actually, it's empty). The singleton implementation is really basic:

```
public class IoCContainer
{
    static IoCContainer()
    {
        Instance = new IoCContainer();
    }

    public static IoCContainer Instance { get; private set; }
}
```

Somehow, it looks like separate assemblies are loaded in separate app domains (or something like that). Anyone knows a solution for this?

Comment: When does `IoCContainer.Instance.Register<IMetadata, Metadata>();` happen?  How are you sure that it has happened by the time you do `IoCContainer.Instance.ResolveType<IMetadata>(); ` ?

Comment: In the ViewModel constructor, just before I step into the actual code. I have debugged it using a different instance of VS2010, and the registration is done *before* the retrieval, but the type I register contains 5 instances, the one that I use to retrieve has 0 (thus it is really a new instance, which is weird for a singleton...)

Comment: The current version of the Silverlight designer does not load controls in a separate app domain. If you have an error in your usercontrol/view the designer will crash. Which makes this issue even weirder.

Comment: Yup, I can simply step through using the debugger of an attached visual studio instance. It is really no threading issue, all occurs in the right order.

It really looks like the static constructor is initialized again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem *seems* to be solved. It might have 2 causes:

First, sometimes visual studio "updates" your references to shared libraries so one points to the bin\debug\mysharedassembly.dll, and the other one still points to ....\lib\mysharedassembly. This is some kind of stupid behavior of VS2010 where it tries to outthink the developer.

Second, I had this definition of the IoC Container:

```
public class IoCContainer
{
    static IoCContainer()
    {
        Instance = new IoCContainer();
    }

    private IoCContainer()
    {

    }

    public static IoCContainer Instance { get; private set; }
}
```

Which I changed to:

```
public class IoCContainer
{
    private static readonly IoCContainer _instance = new IoCContainer;

    private IoCContainer()
    {

    }

    public static IoCContainer Instance { get { return _instance; } }
}
```

Anyway, problem solved :)

Comment: The more I think about it, it *must* be issue 1 (because that might result in an actual different type and thus instance).

Answer (score 0):

Could be a threading issue. Your singleton instance could be instantiated twice by different threads. Have a look at http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html. It explains it in more detail and provides you with a thread safe solution.

Comment: It's no threading issue. This is what I do in the constructor:

public MyViewModel()
{
    IoCContainer.Instance.RegisterType<IMetadata, Metadata>();

    var model = new Model(); <= in this code, the item is used
}